# Реакция поисковика на php редирект header()

Tags: seo, php

Здравствуйте, как относиться поисковики гугл, яндекс и т.д. на php редирект `header()`?
Также, стоит счетчик маркета?

Answer (score 1):

Поисковики относятся к редиректам нормально, есть несколько тонкостей между кодами 302 и 301. Нужно понимать что если вы выдаете 302 (Moved temporary), то поисковик будет опрашивать станицу каждый раз при перестройке индекса, а в случае с 301 (Moved Permanently) обращений будет гораздо меньше.

Из рекомендаций серьезных СЕО-студий (например Ашманов) использовать 302 нужно крайне и крайне осторожно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут гляньте:

- [301 редирект: понятие и настройка](http://comparison-line.ru/301-redirekt-ponyatie-i-nastrojka.html),
- [301 редирект](http://sivway.com/poleznoe/301-redirekt-2.html),
- [поисковики и 301-й редирект](http://chernyshov.kiev.ua/archives/000125.html).